# "Limits" property ignored when deploying a container in a Kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I am deploying a container in Google Kubernetes Engine with this YAML fragment:

```
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: service
        image: registry/service-go:latest
        resources:
          requests:
           memory: "20Mi"
           cpu: "20m"
          limits:
           memory: "100Mi"
           cpu: "50m"
```

But it keeps taking 120m. **Why is "limits" property being ignored?** Everything else is working correctly. If I request 200m, 200m are being reserved, but limit keeps being ignored.

[image]

My Kubernetes version is 1.10.7-gke.1

I only have the default namespace and when executing

> kubectl describe namespace default

```
Name:         default
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>
Status:       Active

No resource quota.

Resource Limits
 Type       Resource  Min  Max  Default Request  Default Limit  Max Limit/Request Ratio
 ----       --------  ---  ---  ---------------  -------------  -----------------------
 Container  cpu       -    -    100m             -              -
```

Comment: Any chance your namespace has a LimitRange set? https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/manage-resources/cpu-constraint-namespace/

Comment: If you run `kubectl describe pod service-85cc4df46d-t6wc9` what do you see? On which page of google cloud console do you found that the pod is limited to 120mCPU?

Comment: Service written in golang?

Comment: @Light.G yes my service is written in Golang.

Comment: @YannC. The page where I see that the CPU is not being limited is in "Node Details" that can be navigated using this path: Google cloud Engine -> Kubernetes Engine -> Clusters -> "testProjectCluster" -> "Nodes Tab" -> gke-testProject-cluster-master-pool

Comment: @coderanger no I'm not using namespaces. If I used them I think the pod yml have configuration precedence over namespace right?

Comment: @YannC. I executed kubectl describe pod service-xxxxx and I the yml looks correct: Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  1
    Limits:
      cpu:     50m
      memory:  100Mi
    Requests:
      cpu:      20m
      memory:   20Mi

Comment: You can't not use namespaces, things are generally in the `default` namespace if not otherwise specified, and a LimtRange takes priority over the pod, that's kind of the whole point :)

Comment: @coderanger I updated the question adding the output of the default namespace description. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Considering Resources Request **Only**

The google cloud console works well, I think you have multiple containers in your pod, this is why. The value shown above is the sum of resources requests declared in your truncated YAML file. You can verify easily with `kubectl`.

First verify the number of containers in you pod.

`kubectl describe pod service-85cc4df46d-t6wc9`

Then, look the description of the node via kubectl, you should have the same informations as the console says.

`kubectl describe node gke-default-pool-abcdefgh...`

### What is the difference between resources request and limit ?

You can imagine your cluster as a big square box. This is the total of your allocatable resources. When you drop a Pod in the big box, Kubernetes will check if there is an empty space for the requested resources of the pod (is the small box fits in the big box?). If there is enough space available, then it will schedule your workload on the selected node.

Resources limits are not taken into account by the scheduler. All is done at the kernel level with CGroups. The goal is to restrict workloads to take all the CPU or Memory on the node they are scheduled on.

If your resources requests == resources limits then, workloads cannot escape their "box" and are not able to use available CPU/Memory next to them. In other terms, your resource are guaranteed for the pod.

But, if the limits are greater than your requests, this is called overcommiting resources. You bet that all the workloads on the same node are not fully loaded at the same time (generally the case).

I recommend to not overcommiting the memory resource, do not let the pod escape the "box" in term of memory, it can leads to OOMKilling.

Comment: You were right, the problem is that I have the image to connect to the google cloud SQL proxy and since the default configured resources request is 100ms. It was  adding the 100ms of the SQL proxy and 20ms of my golang service. Thanks for the help and sorry, it was a really simple thing that I should have detected.

Answer (score 1):

You can try logging into the node running your pod and run:

```
ps -Af | grep docker
```

You'll see the full command line that kubelet sends to docker. Representing the memory limit it should have something like `--memory`.  Note that the request value for memory is only used by the Kubernetes scheduler to determine whether it has exceeded all pods/containers running on a node.

Representing the requests for CPUs you'll see the `--cpu-shares` flag. In this case the limit is not a hard limit but again it's a way for the Kubernetes scheduler to not allocate containers/pod passed that limit when running multiple containers/pods on a specific node.  You can learn more about cpu-shares [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#cpu-share-constraint) and from the Kubernetes side [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-compute-resources-container/#how-pods-with-resource-limits-are-run). So in essence, if you don't have enough workloads on the node, it will always go over its CPU share if it needs to and that's what you are probably seeing.

Docker has other ways of restricting the CPUs such as cpu-period/cpu-quota and cpuset-cpus but not used bu Kubernetes as of this writing. In this, I believe mesos does somehow better when dealing with CPU/memory reservations and quotas imo.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks @Rico, The documentation can be really misleading: "A Container might or might not be allowed to exceed its CPU limit for extended periods of time. However, it will not be killed for excessive CPU usage." And in the official video tutorial from google they mention this parameter really limits the amount of CPU. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xjpHggHKm78&feature=youtu.be&t=2m4s

Comment: I would go with what the documentation says.